# Attaching Events To Dynamically Created Elements With Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I add input dynamically and write event for this input. Event work, but all the second inputs are the same s. I want to do event for each other.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields = 4; //maximum input boxes allowed
            var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
            var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

            var x = 1; //initlal text box count
            $(add_button).click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
                    x++; //text box increment
                    $(wrapper).append('<div><input id="test" class="test"  type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a><br><input id="test2" class="test2" type="text" name="mytext2[]"></div></div>'); //add input box

                    $(".test").on("input", function () {
                        $(this).closest('div').find('.test2').val($(this).val());
                    });
                }
            });

            $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent('div').remove();
                x--;
            });

            $(".test").on("input", function () {
                $(this).closest('div').find('.test2').val($(this).val());
            });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="input_fields_wrap" class="input_fields_wrap">
        <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
        <div><input id="test" class="test" type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
        <div><input id="test2" class="test2" type="text" name="mytext2[]"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ids have to be unique

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I'm afraid it's not at all clear what you're asking.

Comment: When asking others for help, please take the time to format your code with consistent, readable formatting and indentation. (I've fixed it for you on this occasion.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may you need to see the demo as above...it works as you need..i maked some changes in class or jQuery...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields = 4; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input id="test" class="test dynamic"  type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a><br><input id="test2" class="test2 dynamic" type="text" name="mytext2[]"></div></div>'); //add input box

     $(".test").on("input", function() {
  $(this).closest('div').find('.test2').val($(this).val());
    });
 //   Your Event Code Put Here   //
// It Find the all input and add event // 

        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    });

    $(".test").on("input", function() {
        $(this).closest('div').find('.test2').val($(this).val());
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="input_fields_wrap" class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div>
    <input id="test" class="test" type="text" name="mytext[]"/> 
    <bR/> 
    <input id="test2" class="test2" type="text" name="mytext2[]"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! :))))))

Comment: But i copy source code  to jsp file. it doesn`t work.What is happen?

Comment: I change class name. The first input couple not work. But other couple work

Comment: Sorry...but you need to add the classs `test` and `test2` in first input tag  replace with this code...  `<div><input id="test" class="dynamic test" type="text" name="mytext[]"><br><input id="test2" class="dynamic test2" type="text" name="mytext2[]"></div>`

Comment: Please Replace Your First two input box code with Above Code....(Please see in example....)

Comment: I change classes name test and test2. But first input couple not work

Comment: How can you help me

Comment: <div id="input_fields_wrap" class="input_fields_wrap">
            <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
            <div><input id="test" class="test" type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
            <div><input id="test2" class="test2" type="text" name="mytext2[]"></div>
        </div>

Comment: $(wrapper).append('<div><input id="test" class="test"  type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a><br><input id="test2" class="test2" type="text" name="mytext2[]"></div></div>');

Comment: <div id="input_fields_wrap" class="input_fields_wrap"> <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button> <div><input id="test" class="test" type="text" name="mytext[]"><input id="test2" class="test2" type="text" name="mytext2[]"></div> </div>

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to all your dynamically created elements and then attach an event listener to the class before the event is actually created in the following manner:
Assuming the class you'll be giving is **dynamic**:

```
$(document).on('event','.dynamic',function(){
  console.log($(this));
});
```

**UPDATE**:

```
$(document).on('input','.dynamic',function(){
  console.log("Typing in input 1");
});
$(document).on('input','.dynamic2',function(){
  console.log("Typing in input 2");
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields = 4; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input id="test" class="dynamic"  type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a><div><input id="test2" class="dynamic2" type="text" name="mytext2[]"></div></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    });


});
```

**And the HTML would be**

```
<div id="input_fields_wrap" class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input id="test" class="dynamic" type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
    <div><input id="test2" class="dynamic" type="text" name="mytext2[]"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get the same first input result at all input 2. When i click to add button i get the same result at all input 2. But i want to get other result what i set to  input 1

Comment: $(".input_fields_wrap").on("input", "input", function() {
        $(".input_fields_wrap .test2").val($(".input_fields_wrap .test").val());
    });

Comment: Where is this event?

Comment: As these are dynamic sections you will have to use:
$(document).on('input','.dynamic',function(){
  console.log("Typing in input 1");
});
$(document).on('input','.dynamic2',function(){
  console.log("Typing in input 2");
});

Comment: I want to set value to input1 and get it on input2

Answer (score 0):

jQuery first find the all tag and add event. so you can need to assign event after add field...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields = 4; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input id="test" class="test dynamic"  type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a><div><input id="test2" class="test2 dynamic" type="text" name="mytext2[]"></div></div>'); //add input box

 $('.dynamic').on('event',function(){
    // Your Code
});
 //   Your Event Code Put Here   //
// It Find the all input and add event // 

        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    });

    $(".input_fields_wrap").on("input", "input", function() {
        $(".input_fields_wrap .test2").val($(".input_fields_wrap .test").val());
    });

});
```

Comment: $(wrapper).append('<div><input id="test" class="test dynamic"  type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a><div><input id="test2" class="test2 dynamic" type="text" name="mytext2[]"></div></div>');

Comment: i add the class dynamic in input please see above

Comment: I want to set value to input1 and get it on input2